# Is it valid to put a class object in multiprocessing.Process as its argument?

Tags: python

I'd like to create a process like this:
multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(object))
An object in args, is it valid?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For something to be passed to/between processes in python, it must be "pickleable". See this official documentation page: [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

Generally, for classes to be pickleable they must be defined at the top level of the module (the .py file), which is the most common situation.